# What is the range of a Pokemon's weight and height?

Tags: pokemon-go

My starter Squirtle is a bit pudgy with XL dimensions, and I wonder if he will need a specialty store for his goggles once he grows up more. Is XL already the max or are there XXXL etc. sizes as well?

Also, is the range same for all Pokemon; or different depending on the species? (e.g. no XS charizards?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of actual numbers (as in, how many kg for XL and what's the absolute max), there is not yet enough information to give a solid answer. Remember the game came out recently (at the time of writing), and therefore little information is available.

However, Pokemon are rated on a scale of XS to XL (with others just not being recorded). Pokemon of *any* species can fall anywhere within this range, so an XS Charizard is just as easy as an XL Weedle.

Answer (score 1):

Within the data from [Pokemon GO GAME_MASTER protobuf decoded](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf), although there is no reference to XS/XL, each pokemon has a weight/height standard deviation from average to determine its size divisions.  The first few I checked show deviations of 12.5%.  The XS/XL tags seem to apply when a pokemon's size is two deviations away.  Further tags could be introduced in the app later.  However, Professor Willow's size appraisal uses a combination of both weight/height.